# I can't run the manta.exe in Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmake, cmake-gui

Environment: python 3.7, cmake 3.19.0, Visual Studio Community 2019, Qt5.9.9(including MinGW)

I downloaded the package in http://mantaflow.com/download.html and its github, I was trying to install it but failed in run the manta.exe.

Here is my installation step:(after downloading the environment, I refered in https://blog.csdn.net/u012685679/article/details/84436953)

1.Unzip the mantaflow-master, mkdir the build

2.Open Cmake, choose the Browse Source and the Browse Build

3.Click the "Configue"

4.In the table, it listed something, add the Qt-something, click the GUI and OPENMP (I don't know why, just refer to that webside..)
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKuLv.png)

5.Click the "Generate"

6.Open the "..\mantaflow-master\build\MantaFlow.sln" in the Visual Studio.(Administrator)

7.Set "menta"({ALL_BUILD, manta, prep, ZERO_CHECK}) "Debug" to "Release", set as startup project

8.copy the python37.dll to python37_d.dll(They are all in one folder, similarly hereinafter), copy the python37.lib to python37_d.lib in ..\lib, delete " # pragma comment(lib,"python37_d.lib") ", and "# define Py_DEBUG" in pyconfig.h

9.Debug in Visual Studio.

The process didn't notice something after it generate manta.exe. It noticed the error about 0xc000007b which meant that it didn't run manta.exe. I don't know how to fix the problem. Thanks for your advice.

I'm sorry about my poor English, if you can't understand my expression or you need more detail in my computer environment or something, please send to me.

Answer (score 0):

The manual states that "Manta does not link or run on windows" but can be compiled to the library level. Have you manged running Manta on Windows?
Manual: https://github.com/Illumina/manta/blob/master/docs/developerGuide/README.md#windows-development-support